# How to listen to table item text changes?

Tags: swt

How can I listen to an SWT `Table` for any change to the texts of its items?

I don't find anything on `Table` or on `TableItem` that is similar to the `addModifyListener` methods that are avilaible on for example `Text` and `Combo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user can't change the text of the items in a plain `Table` so there is no need for a listener.

To allow the user to change the text you need to set up a `TableEditor`. The editor will use a control such as `Text` which can have a modify listener.

Comment: I was hoping that one part of my program could listen to changes made by another part of the program (this other part is outside my control). So that the listening part would be notified of all changes, regardless of how or why the changes were make.

Comment: There isn't anything like that. Ideally the part making the changes should provide some sort of notification API (for example using the Event Broker in an Eclipse RCP). If it doesn't do that you will be struggling.